# Are MySql transactions mutually exclusive?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

In my application I want to do something like

```
1) INSERT INTO APPLICATION VALUES(...);
```

And then I want to retrieve the ID (which is AUTO_INCREMENT) of the last record inserted into the APPLICATION table and store it in another table like...

```
2) $last_rec = $this->con->query("SELECT ID FROM APPLICATION ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
3) INSERT INTO INFO(A_ID, ...) VALUES($last_rec, ...);
```

I am using transaction and everything is working fine but I am not sure if another transaction could insert a row in APPLICATION just after step-1 is complete, if that occurs then the wrong APPLICATION.ID would be stored in INFO.A_ID.

Any suggestions as to how should I handle such situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

"For `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the most recently generated `ID` is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client.

It is not even changed if you update another `AUTO_INCREMENT` column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0).

**Using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid.**"

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend against `LAST_INSERT_ID()` as it might throw up wrong id in case of simultaneous insertions in the table...

For example...if you have 2 simultaneous transactions and you want to get 1st of the 2 transaction id.....`last_insert_id()` would failed here as it doesn't know which was the last correct insertion

instead use `mysqli->insert_id`

```
$result = $mysqli->query( /*insert query here */);
echo 'The ID is: '.$mysqli->insert_id;
```

**Ref** :  [**mysqli.insert-id**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: No, they are exactly the same thing. LAST_INSERT_ID() is scoped to the session, and will never give a value generated by another session.

Comment: just a doubt..is it possible that `user` can do 2 transactions in single session???? :|

Comment: Yes, a single session can consist of multiple transactions in serial, but that doesn't matter. MySQL reports the last auto-increment value generated in the current session, regardless of transactions.